# Memory usage of a function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to measure the memory usage of a function. I would like to compare the memory requirements for different methods of solving a linear system of equations. I am looking for a way of measuring it like this:

```
N = 100;
A = rand(N, N);
b = rand(N, 1);

mem1 = memory(sol = A \ b);

mem2 = memory(sol = sparse(A) \ b);
```

Comment: There seem to be some undocumented ways of doing this: [one](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/profiling-matlab-memory-usage/) and [two](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/undocumented-profiler-options/). Them being undocumented does mean that they can be removed without noticed (or might already have been removed). IIRC there's no clean way such as the profiler (which is for runtime per call), forcing you to rely on undocumented behaviour.

Comment: Do note that your example is a bit silly, since `sparse()` stores 3 numbers for every value (row index, column index and value), which only makes sense if some 75% or more of your matrix is empty (taking overhead into account). Using `sparse()` on a full matrix is going to take ~3.5 times more memory than just using the full matrix itself.

Comment: Yeah the example is a bit silly, as the matrix is everything but sparse. I used it here to have a minimal working example. The problem I am working on however, is a finite difference approach to solving a pde. Thus the matrix is always going to be very sparse. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The actual matrix looks like this:
`h = 1/100;
diag_mat = -2 * (1/h^2 + 1/h^2) * eye(N) + 1/h^2 * diag(ones(N-1, 1), -1) + 1/h^2 * diag(ones(N-1, 1), 1);

A = kron(eye(N), diag_mat) + 1/h^2 * diag(ones(N * N - N, 1), N) + 1/h^2 * diag(ones(N * N - N, 1), -N);`

Comment: And I've added some solvers myself and I would like to see how they perform in terms of memory as well